# Self Cross apply table data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a below table

```
ID       Level  StoreId   
2678540   3      A
2678540   7      A
2678540   3      B
2678540   7      B
2678540   3      C
```

I need out put like Below

```
ID      A   B   C   D   E    
2678540 3   3   3   0   0
2678540 3   7   3   0   0
2678540 7   3   3   0   0
2678540 7   7   3   0   0
```

Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: Look into `Pivot`

Comment: What is the logic here?

Comment: How do you distinct `A` and `B` columns, on the input, they're exactly the same, but in the output, they differ...

Answer (score 0):

If StoreID 'A' always exists:

```
select tA.ID, tA.Level as A, tB.Level as B, tC.Level as C , 0 as D, 0 as E
from Table1 tA 
cross apply (select Level from Table1 t2 where tA.Id=t2.Id and t2.StoreId = 'B') tB
cross apply (select Level from Table1 t2 where tA.Id=t2.Id and t2.StoreId = 'C') tC
where tA.StoreId = 'A'
```